# Google maps api not working on postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using google maps API to load streets in a textbox.It is working properly.My problem is that on postback the initialize method in javascript is not working and data is not loading

I am using

```
            
             function initialize() {
            //my code
             }
             google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Please help me

Comment: What is the error message (check in error console in FF or Chrome) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to re-initialize the map on post-back as the code will not run again. If you are using an UpdatePanel a way to do this would be to bind to the `end_RequestHandler` i.e.

```
var prm = window.Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);

function endRequestHandler()
{
    // Initialize the map again
}
```

Comment: I have a problem now.i have popup windows in my page.when i am openinig it scrip error occurs.